# Adobe PDF Document not allowing Javascript to calculate on mobile devices (Android / iOS)

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I believe it this worked on mobile devices at one point but now its not working.

MainDate is a calendar date elected by the user using a formatted text box, and the bottom code was implemented individually in separate text box's (sun-sat) which used the below to calculate the date. I incremented the number 0 from "Add days to date" in each text box to get the correct date.

```
// Custom Calculate script for MainDate field
(function () {

    // Get date entered into the MainDate field
    var sDate = getField("MainDate").valueAsString;

    // Convert string to date
    var d = util.scand("mm/dd/yy", sDate);

   // Add days to date
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 0);

    // Populate this field with the result
    if (sDate) {
        event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yy", d);
    } else {
        event.value = "";
    }
})();
```

Again I believe at one point it did work on mobile devices or I might be completely wrong. Is there a fix or another method to use to be able to calculate the date via mobile devices?

*Update: I tested qPDF Viewer, Xodo, foxit and a few other unknown editors and no luck on the Android side....*

revised code:

```
// Custom Calculate script for MainDate field 
(function () {

var MDate = getField("MainDate").value;

    // Get date entered into the MainDate field
    var sDate = MDate;

    // Convert string to date
    var d = util.scand("mm/dd/yy", sDate);

   // Add days to date
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 6);

    // Populate this field with the result
    if (sDate) {
        event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yy", d);
    } else {
        event.value = "";
    }
})();
```

This now works with the Foxit android app but not in Xodo nor Adobe... Thanks!

Comment: It depends a lot on the PDF viewer you are using on your mobile phone. Most available ones are too dumb to deal with JavaScript. You might look out specifically for a smart PDF viewer.

Comment: Speaking just for the Adobe mobile viewers, I've ***never*** known Field.valueAsString to be supported. Only Field.value is supported. You also might want to prefix getField() with "this."

Answer (score 0):

> Speaking just for the Adobe mobile viewers, I've never known Field.valueAsString to be supported. Only Field.value is supported. You also might want to prefix getField() with "this." – joelgeraci

The fix works on Foxit and unsure of what apps for iOS...